# Xcode 6.3 shows inconsistent errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

I just downloaded Xcode 6.3 and started fixing errors, caused by the change to Swift 1.2. My problem is that Xcode shows errors in an inconsistent way. I get some errors more often than others and some of them just disappear for ages, before reappearing randomly (I guess). I have to check every file after I perform a build, in order to see the errors in it. I will be thankful for any suggestions for this problem. If you need further clarification (which wouldn't be surprising, since my explanations are not the brightest), don't hesitate to leave a comment. For example: these three errors appear right after the build has failed and disappear in ~ten seconds.
[image]

Comment: I think you'll want to show an example with the actual errors and inconsistencies, otherwise you'll likely get random responses in regards to your random errors, which is entirely too much randomness.

Comment: "three errors appear right after the build has failed and disappear in ~ten seconds." You have 10 seconds to solve the errors pretty legit ;)

Comment: Yeah, @Roma-MT, I spent the last 10 seconds laughing at your comment, instead of fixing the errors ;) Thank you for the suggestion, I'L'I - I edited the post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `super.init()` or any other methods/inherited properties until you initialize every `let` property you have declared.